# hostname - command not found issue

Tags: hostname

I am installing BOWTIE as below in amazonlinux:

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/bowtie-bio/files/bowtie2/2.2.4/bowtie2-2.2.4-source.zip
unzip bowtie2-2.2.4-source.zip
cd bowtie2-2.2.4
make
echo "BOWTIE installed successfully."
```

I am getting the  below error when I issue the 'make' command:

```
/bin/sh: hostname: command not found
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue

```
which: no hostname in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
bash-4.2# hostname
bash: hostname: command not found
```

Comment: Maybe you need to install the `net-tools` in your amazon Linux environment...

Comment: thanks very much it works  now :)

Comment: Glad to help @nadish :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to install

```
yum install bind-utils -y
```